# How to resolve the Python error "Required argument 'x' not found"

Tags: python, opencv

I'm a beginner and I got an error while worked with Python OpenCV.

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
front_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('../haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('mimika-1024x572.jpg')


faces = front_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minsize=(30,30)
)
#for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
#    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 155), 3)

print (faces)

cv2.imshow('frame', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/cv/test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    minsize=(30,30)
TypeError: Required argument 'image' (pos 1) not found
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: what do you think that error means?

Comment: Please refrain from txtspk when posting here. You don't need to "please help me" pleading, but do try to avoid "plz" at all costs. Full words are not too much trouble to type.

Answer (score 1):

`detectMultiScale` requires an image as the first argument, but you have forgotten to pass it.

Try:

```
faces = front_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    img,  # don't forget this!
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minsize=(30,30)
)
```